# SML: how to clear the buffer?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am using the SML of New Jersey command window, and I want to clear the buffer from all the variables and functions. Is there any command(s) for doing it?
Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl-D (or Ctrl-Z on Windows) :)  No other I know of.

Comment: Dosn't work. ^Z closes the console, and ^D dos nothing.

Comment: That's the point. Closing the interpreter is the only way (that I, or Andreas, know of) to clear all bindings. Ctrl-D does exactly that on linux.